# Can OP be used to refer to someone who has posted an answer?

Tags: discussion, terminology

[Stack Exchange Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/166025) mentions that `OP` is:

> Original Poster. A quick way to point at the person who wrote the
>   question.

Is there any such terminology to point at the person who posted an answer? Or `OP` can be used for both? In later case we would have to update the Glossary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

However, it's more commonly used for askers. If, however, you write "OP" in a comment to an answer, people will (probably) assume you are talking about the answerer. To avoid any confusion you can simply write something like "The OP of this answer..." instead.